# LibreOffice C++ API missing headers

Tags: c++, api, libreoffice

I currently trying to use LibreOffice in headless mode to convert documents to pdf.
I want to use the LibreOffice C++ API to get this done, but my problem is that I can't find some of the headers that are used in the LibreOffice C++ examples.

```
#include <com/sun/star/beans/XPropertySet.hpp>
#include <com/sun/star/bridge/XUnoUrlResolver.hpp>
#include <com/sun/star/frame/Desktop.hpp>
#include <com/sun/star/frame/XComponentLoader.hpp>
#include <com/sun/star/lang/XMultiComponentFactory.hpp>
#include <com/sun/star/registry/XSimpleRegistry.hpp>
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and installed the package libreoffice-dev.

Can someone explain me how to correctly use the LibreOffice C++ API?

Comment: Does adding option `-Ipath/to/Libre_office_com` help? If you are using IDE, browse and add `path/to/Libre_office_com` to additional header files. One more thing, you can try after replace `#include <com/sun/star/beans/XPropertySet.hpp>` with `#include "com/sun/star/beans/XPropertySet.hpp"`

Comment: under "com/sun/star/" I only got the folder/namespace "uno".

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
The files have to generated from the IDL files with the cppumaker tool(delivered with the SDK). From the folder containing cppumaker I ran this command as root.

```
./cppumaker -Gc -O"/usr/include/libreoffice/com/sun/star" /usr/lib/ure/share/misc/types.rdb /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/offapi.rdb /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/oovbaapi.rdb
```